# Django models file update for many to many query

Tags: python, django, model

All,
Here is my dilemma.  I've created the Django models.py file with 2 classes, CustTeamMembers and CustTeamName.  There is a many to many relationship between the two called cust_members.  What this means is a team member can be on many teams and many teams can have the same member.

What I need to create is a way to choose one member for each team that is a team leader.  That team member needs to come from the cust_members list.

So far I have not had any luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# This will hold the team members
class CustTeamMembers(models.Model):
    member_first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_last_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_email      = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    member_phone      = models.CharField(max_length = 25, blank=True)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ['member_last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member_first_name + ' ' + self.member_last_name

# This will hold the customer name
class CustTeamName(models.Model):
    cust_name    = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    #cust_lead    = models.ForeignKey(CustTeamMembers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    cust_members = models.ManyToManyField(CustTeamMembers, blank=True)
    cust_meet    = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank=True)
    cust_status  = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cust_name

    def get_members(self):
        return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.cust_members.all()]
```

~Ed

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) and customize the intermediate table. Something like this.

```
from django.db import models

# This will hold the team members
class CustTeamMembers(models.Model):
    member_first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_last_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_email      = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    member_phone      = models.CharField(max_length = 25, blank=True)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ['member_last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member_first_name + ' ' + self.member_last_name

# This will hold the customer name
class CustTeamName(models.Model):
    cust_name    = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    #cust_lead    = models.ForeignKey(CustTeamMembers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    cust_members = models.ManyToManyField(CustTeamMembers, blank=True, through="TeamsAndMembers")
    cust_meet    = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank=True)
    cust_status  = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cust_name

    def get_members(self):
        return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.cust_members.all()]

class TeamsAndMembers(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(CustTeamName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey(CustTeamMembers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```